# How can I run common code in tests using Karma + Jasmine + AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm using Karma to run my unit tests against an AngularJS application. The problem is that I use the ui-router plugin, and the fact that it makes some XHR requests to run the templates forces me to mock those requests. Therefore, I see myself repeating this for every test file:

```
  beforeEach(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('templates/layout.html', '');
    $templateCache.put('templates/dashboard/index.html', '');
    $templateCache.put('templates/session/login.html', '');
  });
```

How can I run this piece of code for all my unit tests? I tried googling, but no luck. Also, should I be doing this in some other way? Please share your opinions.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into ng-html2js-preprocessor:

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor

It will batch up all your templates into a template cache module (that uses [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) under the hood) that you can use:

```
describe('SOMETHING', function() {
    beforeEach(module('templates'));
```

Comment: Thanks, will do. I'm leaving now, but tomorrow morning I'll try it and then I'll post the results.

Comment: I was thinking the wrong way. This plugin puts all the templates in $templateCache, so I don't need to add them all the time. Thanks!